# which is the best allocation way in C++

Tags: c++, memory

**first case:**

```
void func(int size)
{
  int arr[size];

  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
   arr[i]=1;

  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
   cout<<arr[i];

}

int main()
{
  func(6);

  return 0;
}

or,
```

**second case**

```
void func(int size)
{
  int *ptr = new int[size];

  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    ptr[i]=1;

  delete[] ptr;
}
```

**Query**:

What is the difference between either two(Is first case dynamic allocation here)?

Which is the best to use(since elements are 6, is first the best choice)?

Is first case called as dynamic stack allocation?

Comment: There's no way to tell without context, but I generally avoid both of those (assuming you even just replace the VLA with a templated size) in favour of containers that offer benefits beyond these.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is, if size is relatively small, you can just allocate the array on the stack, to avoid unnecessary wasted cycles from new and delete operations :)

Comment: @chris yes i will keep that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First one is not C++ — variable length array is not allowed by the current Standard (C++11) — it might be C++14 but that is not yet released. If your compiler compiles it fine, then it is just a compiler-extension: if you're using GCC, compile it with `-pedantic-errors`, you will see error.

The second one is a bad solution: *any* resource should be wrapped in a resource managing class, popularly referred to as RAII class. It is a dangerous idea to leave them open like that. Search for RAII on this site, you will see lots of topics on it.

There is a superior solution : use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: the first case compiles and runs fine

Comment: @user1502952: If you're using GCC, compile it with `-pedantic-errors`

Comment: You might want to explain further why the second case is usually a bad solution (i.e. increases chances of heap corruption).

Answer (score 1):

Both do exactly the same thing. The only difference is that in VLA's(Variable Length Arrays) the compiler takes care of the allocation, de-allocation, etc.
Thus, VLAs simplify storage management of programs since some uses that require manual use of new and delete can be replaced by VLAs.
Note that both use the heap segment for memory allocation.
Read this : http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-cwhy-variable-length-arrays/184401444
Well I would suggest that you use the STL vector class which has loads of functionality and doesn't bother you with such issues and is very easy to get along with.
Here it is : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: But they don't both use "the stack". At least not for the array.